# Producing equal results for column entries which are the same

Tags: r, matrix

I have the piece of code below. What i want is alter the code
such that when the column entries for mat are the same, i get the same result in their respective positions in summation without it performing the fit operation?

So instead of getting

```
             1    3    5    1    7    1
             2    4    6    2    8    2  
             3    9   12    5   16    4
```

I want

```
           1    3    5    1    7    1
           2    4    6    2    8    2
           3    9   12    3   16    3
```

```
   set.seed(123)
   fit = function(A){
       x = A[1]
       y = A[2]
       z = sum(sample((x+y),2))
       return(z)
  }
  mat= matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,7,8,1,2),nrow=2,ncol=6)
  summation=apply(mat, 2, FUN = 'fit')
  newmat=rbind(mat,summation)
  newmat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out columns that are duplicates and replace the corresponding `summation` value with the first value of `summation` so that you get the same value.

```
fit = function(A){
  x = A[1]
  y = A[2]
  z = sum(sample((x+y),2))
  return(z)
}
mat= matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,7,8,1,2),nrow=2,ncol=6)
summation=apply(mat, 2, FUN = 'fit')
vals <- apply(mat, 2, paste0, collapse = '-')
summation <- ave(summation, match(vals, unique(vals)), FUN = function(x) x[1])
newmat=rbind(mat,summation)
newmat
```

---

To pass only unique columns to `fit` function we can do :

```
fit = function(A){
  x = A[1]
  y = A[2]
  z = sum(sample((x+y),2))
  return(z)
}
mat= matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,7,8,1,2),nrow=2,ncol=6)
vals <- apply(mat, 2, paste0, collapse = '-')
summation <- apply(mat[, !duplicated(vals)], 2, fit)
summation <- summation[match(vals, unique(vals))]
newmat=rbind(mat,summation)
newmat
```

Comment: Is it possible to run the first apply function on the unique columns of mat and later fix the value obtained in summation of the column entry of c(1,2) for the other duplicates, so that the other duplicates do not go through the summation process in the first apply function? I want to avoid the other duplicates from going through the first apply function because in my problem z is a simulation process that takes a long time to determine. Thank you.

Comment: `mat[, !duplicated(t(mat))]` would give you only unique columns in `mat`.

Comment: Yes that gives the unique columns. I use **unique(mat,MARGIN=2)** to get the unique columns. But in my problem i want say **mat1=unique(mat,MARGIN=2)**. Then run **summation=apply(mat1, 2, FUN = 'fit')**. Lastly, form **newmat** but use the result value of c(1,2) in the summation process which is 3 to put in **newmat** when it comes across c(1,2). Thank you.